# Maximum number of random variables to make pairwise correlation coefficient less than C

Tags: statistics, correlation

Assuming N random variables $X_1, X_2, ..., X_N$, each has $m$ samples, (e.g. $m=3$). what is the maximum N such that **all pairwise sample correlation coefficients** $\rho_{X_i, X_j}$ are less than some constant $C$? (e.g. $C=0.6$)

Comment: What does this mean?  You can have any number of random variables all having any given positive pairwise correlation.  The problem comes with negative correlations as you need the correlation matrix to be positive semi-definite

Comment: @Henry you are right, the restriction is each random variable has only a fixed number of samples, say 3. I edit the problem